# MatSelect with multiple does not display checkbox

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following template:

```
<mat-form-field
    class="search-form"
    floatLabel="always"
    appearance="fill">
    <mat-select placeholder="Items"
                [compareWith]="compare"
                [(ngModel)]="params.itemId"
                multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items"
                  [innerText]="item.name"
                  [value]="item.id">
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

and the following parts related to `MatSelect` component:

```
items: any[] = [];
params: {};
```

My component displays like this:

[image]

I can select multiple, and retrieve the value in an array format as expected, however, I'd expect to display my content with a checkbox like the in the documentation:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `[innerText]` property of `<mat-option>`. Converting my template for `MatOption` to :

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of items"
                  [value]="item.id">
    {{item.name}}
</mat-option>
```

instead of:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of items"
                  [value]="item.id"
                  [innerText]="item.name">
</mat-option>
```

resolves the issue.